# SharePoint Document Library sync. with One Drive for Business Error "not supported by this version"

Tags: sharepoint-online, office, onedrive-for-business

I'm trying to Sync. SharePoint Document library to One drive for business

[image: One Drive Sync option]

It popup the launch application

[image: One drive launch app]

by accepting that launch application option

[image: Doc lib url]

[image]

**Error : Server is trying to access using and authentication protocol not supported by this version of Office**

How can I find Correct version of office for that

Current scenario :

- SharePoint : SharePoint online
- Office     : office 2016

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue by MSFT.

> Solution

A fix was released for the Click-to-Run version of the OneDrive for Business sync client. By default, Click-to-Run installations of Microsoft Office 2013 and Office 2016 are configured to automatically update your Office installation when new updates are made publicly available. If your Click-to-Run version of Office doesn't update automatically, see the following Microsoft website:
2753538 Automatic updating for Office 2013 and Office 2016 Click-to-Run is not enabled

You can also try workaround mention in same kb
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3142311